# How to extract Atom/RSS

Tags: vb.net, rss, extract, atom-feed, selectnodes

Given a URL, if it has any RSS nodes, then I am adding to the database.

e.g.:

For [this URL](http://webclip.in/rss.aspx?u=iamgame), `rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item").Count` is greater than zero.

But for [the atom url](http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/user/02179771748407903760/state/com.google/broadcast), `rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item").count` is equal to zero.

How can I check if the Atom/RSS URL has any nodes or not? I have tried for `rssDoc.SelectNodes("feed/entry").Count`, but is giving me zero count.

```
Public Shared Function HasRssItems(ByVal url as string) As Boolean
Dim myRequest As WebRequest
Dim myResponse As WebResponse
Try
    myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    myRequest.Timeout = 5000
    myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()

    Dim rssStream As Stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim rssDoc As New XmlDocument()
    rssDoc.Load(rssStream)

    Return rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item").Count > 0
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
Finally
    myResponse.Close()
End Try
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem here is that the XML "node path" on this line:

`Return rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item").Count > 0`

is only valid for [RSS feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rss), not [ATOM feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29).

One way I've got over this in the past is to use a simple function to convert an ATOM feed into an RSS feed.  Of course, you could go the other way, or not convert at all, however, converting to a single format enables you to write one "generic" chunk of code that will pull out the various elements of a feed's items that you may be interested in (i.e. date, title etc.)

There is an [ATOM to RSS Converter article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ATOM_To_RSS_Converter.aspx) on Code Project that provides such a conversion, however, that is in C#.  I have previously manually converted this to VB.NET myself, so here's the VB.NET version:

```
Private Function AtomToRssConverter(ByVal atomDoc As XmlDocument) As XmlDocument
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = atomDoc
    Dim xmlNode As XmlNode = Nothing
    Dim mgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
    mgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://purl.org/atom/ns#")
    Const rssVersion As String = "2.0"
    Const rssLanguage As String = "en-US"
    Dim rssGenerator As String = "RDFFeedConverter"
    Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim xmlWriter As New XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Nothing)
    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    Dim feedTitle As String = ""
    Dim feedLink As String = ""
    Dim rssDescription As String = ""

    xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//atom:title", mgr)
    If xmlNode Is Nothing Then
          This looks like an ATOM v1.0 format, rather than ATOM v0.3.
        mgr.RemoveNamespace("atom", "http://purl.org/atom/ns#")
        mgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    End If

    xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//atom:title", mgr)
    If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
        feedTitle = xmlNode.InnerText
    End If
    xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//atom:link/@href", mgr)(2)
    If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
        feedLink = xmlNode.InnerText
    End If
    xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//atom:tagline", mgr)
    If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
        rssDescription = xmlNode.InnerText
    End If
    xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//atom:subtitle", mgr)
    If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
        rssDescription = xmlNode.InnerText
    End If

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("rss")
    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("version", rssVersion)
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("channel")
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("title", feedTitle)
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("link", feedLink)
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("description", rssDescription)
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("language", rssLanguage)
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("generator", rssGenerator)
    Dim items As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//atom:entry", mgr)
    If items Is Nothing Then
        Throw New FormatException("Atom feed is not in expected format. ")
    Else
        Dim title As String = [String].Empty
        Dim link As String = [String].Empty
        Dim description As String = [String].Empty
        Dim author As String = [String].Empty
        Dim pubDate As String = [String].Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To items.Count - 1
            Dim nodTitle As XmlNode = items(i)
            xmlNode = nodTitle.SelectSingleNode("atom:title", mgr)
            If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
                title = xmlNode.InnerText
            End If
            Try
                link = items(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:link[@rel= alternate ]", mgr).Attributes("href").InnerText
            Catch ex As Exception
                link = items(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:link", mgr).Attributes("href").InnerText
            End Try
            xmlNode = items(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:content", mgr)
            If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
                description = xmlNode.InnerText
            End If
            xmlNode = items(i).SelectSingleNode("//atom:name", mgr)
            If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
                author = xmlNode.InnerText
            End If
            xmlNode = items(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:issued", mgr)
            If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
                pubDate = xmlNode.InnerText
            End If
            xmlNode = items(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:updated", mgr)
            If Not xmlNode Is Nothing Then
                pubDate = xmlNode.InnerText
            End If
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("item")
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("title", title)
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("link", link)
            If pubDate.Length < 1 Then
                pubDate = Date.MinValue.ToString()
            End If
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("pubDate", Convert.ToDateTime(pubDate).ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss G\MT"))
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("author", author)
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("description", description)
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        Next
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        xmlWriter.Flush()
        xmlWriter.Close()
    End If
    Dim retDoc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim outStr As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray())
    retDoc.LoadXml(outStr)
    Return retDoc
End Function
```

Usage is fairly straight forward.  Simply load in your ATOM feed into an `XmlDocument` object and pass it to this function, and you'll get an `XmlDocument` object back, in RSS format!

If you're interested, I've put an entire [RSSReader class up on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/f5bc7b95f)